# emailjs not getting resolved even after installing it

Tags: reactjs, npm, module, smtp

I ran the command `npm install emailjs-com --save` in my project to install email-js but when I `import emailjs from "emialjs-com"` I'm getting the error can't resolve 'emialjs-com' in '/Users/visheshgoyal/Desktop/Eternal/eternalwebapp/src/components'. Can someone suggest what can be the possible error.

Comment: "This package has been deprecated" [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-com)

Comment: ohh then which package to use this  one is also not working it is there in there docs for installation @emailjs/browser

Comment: https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/

Answer (score 4):

The SDK name has been changed to '@emailjs/browser'. To fix this problem, install emailjs by running:

```
npm install @emailjs/browser
```

Use the current SDK name instead of 'emailjs-com', which has been deprecated.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-com

Answer (score 0):

May be `@emailjs/browser` has not installed in emailjs. You can install this manually by running:

```
mailjs/browser
```